# How to unit test a filter using cache2k

Tags: java, unit-testing, cache2k

i am having a servlet filter which uses cache,the code basically goes like this

```
public class CustomFilter implements Filter {
    private  final Cache<String, ClientRequest> cache;
    @Autowired
    public CustomFilter(Service service){
    cache = Caching.getCachingProvider().getCacheManager()
            .createCache("requestsCache", 
            ExtendedMutableConfiguration.of(
                    Cache2kBuilder.of(String.class, 
            ClientRequest.class).entryCapacity(100)                                
            .expireAfterWrite(1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS)));
    }
}
```

Any thoughts about how can i unit test methods in this filter which use this class ? thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract `Cache<String, ClientRequest>` creation to external configuration and inject it through filter constructor:

```
public class CustomFilter implements Filter {
  private final Cache<String, ClientRequest> cache;

  public CustomFilter(Cache<String, ClientRequest> cache) {
    this.cache = Objects.requireNonNull(cache);
  }
```

That way you can mock the cache in your unit tests. This will allow to test `CustomFilter` business logic in isolation, without having to deal with complexity of the cache.

After that you might need a separate test for your cache configuration e.g. by using a property to define expiry timeout.

Comment: thanks, this should work, but while i integrate the controller using mockMvc, can we force the filter to use this ? why i am asking is, for uni testing i can add a mock cache, but integration test use mockMvc with just the path.. i can ask this as a seperate question too.

Comment: If you are using Spring Boot you can create `@WebMvcTes` with `@MockBean @Primary Cache<?, ?> mockCache;` and it should work. Standard auto-wireing rules apply.

Comment: but i am not using spring boot's cache, using cache2k, will that work ?

Comment: It's standard bean `@Autowire` order and overrides logic, which cache you are using it makes no difference as it's based on names and types.